# .net core [Authorize] using ClaimsIdentity with AAD groups

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, azure-active-directory

I am seeing this in my `((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).Claims`:

[image]

How do I make use of these group GUID's I am getting from our Azure AD (to secure the endpoint based on group membership)?

```
[Authorize(Roles="<group guid here>")]
```

or

```
[Authorize("<group guid here>")]
```

Or do I need to set something up in the `startup.cs` file?

Answer (score 4):

You could use policy in asp.net core , use an attribute with a named policy then you define the policy in startup to require group claim and set allowed Group ID :

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add MVC services to the services container.
            services.AddMvc();

            // Add Authentication services.
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => sharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);


            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "CanAccessGroup",
                    policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "8e39f882-3453-4aeb-9efa-f6ac6ad8e2e0"));
            });
        }
```

Then in controller :

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessGroup")]
 public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
```

If the group id is not in the user group claims, it will redirect user to access denied page , you could also write your policy rules logic as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) .

Comment: I think you can also set the RoleClaimType and then use Roles, but this is a better solution.

Comment: @juunas: Using roles is discouraged, as it's very inflexible and requires the roles to be hardcoded. Whereas the policies allows modules to plugin their own policies or override existing ones. With claims you can do everything you could do with roles and much more

Comment: Yup, exactly why I said this is better ;)

Comment: How would one grant access to more than one group for a resource?  In the majority of the areas of my application, I want specific departments to have access to specific portions of the site, but grant access to everywhere to Administrators.