# how to get the group membership?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the Roles of a logged in user , using using openID connect with "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"

I can hit breakpoints on    OnTokenValidated , and  OnTicketReceived . in my controller decorated with    [Authorize], User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true     ,but   User.IsInRole("admin")  is false    <-- this is a group in my tenant, and my account is a member.
Any suggestions on getting role Info? Do i need to implement   OnUserInformationReceived  ? Any examples?

I am following the wiki : [Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

Thanks,Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group membership is not included in ID token by default , you can follow below steps to configure your application to receive group claims :

1. In your application page, click on `Manifest` to open the inline manifest editor.
2. Edit the manifest by locating the `groupMembershipClaims` setting, and setting its value to `All` (or to `SecurityGroup` if you are not interested in Distribution Lists).
3. Save the manifest.

   ```
   {
     ...
     "createdDateTime": "",
     "groupMembershipClaims": "All",
     "identifierUris": [],
     ...
   }
   ```
4. To receive the groups claim with the object id of the security groups, make sure that the user accounts you plan to sign-in in is assigned to a few security groups in this AAD tenant.

You could use policy in asp.net core , use an attribute with a named policy then you define the policy in startup to require group claim and set allowed Group ID . See code sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645055/5751404) .

In addition, `User.IsInRole("admin")` will check whether `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: admin` exists in user claims . You can also set the RoleClaimType to use group information and then use Roles .

Comment: Nan, 
Does this work in Asp.net core 2.2? i get a error : 'AzureADOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SignInScheme' 

This is the section of my startup :

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


            // Add Authentication services.
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => sharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: Do you use the default `work or school account` template ? why do you need the `services. services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => sharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);`

Comment: 'No Authentication' template initial  project. 
I  added the property :
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "CanAccessGroup",
                    policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "guid of my admin group"));
            });

and decorated my controller with    [Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessGroup")] but something is not working because i get access denied :
https://localhost:44338/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2FPlanes
 I verified my login account is a member of the admins group

Comment: in     OnTicketReceived(), i added           var xx = ctx.Principal.FindAll(x => x.Type == "groups").ToList(); , which comes back with empty list. Any troubleshooting ideas? Thanks, Peter

Comment: Do you modify the `groupMembershipClaims` of application in azure portal ?

Comment: Yes. the app registration manifest   "groupMembershipClaims": "All",

Comment: Not reproduce , it get the claims include groups claim , after modify to All in manifest , please confirm you save the change .  You can also decode the id token to confirm whether group claims is included .

Comment: yes, i saved the manifest. i will create a new  project using work or school . I assume domain is microsoft.onmicrosfot.com since I use Azure AD.

Comment: I setup a  new solution for work and school accounts  ,  and said 

    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",

    "TenantId": "common",
    "ClientId": "myclientid",

but  same problem.
IsAuthenticated true  , but   User.IsInRole("admin") =false

Comment: As i said , you should not use User.IsInRole("admin") , you need to set policy to check groups claims