# When creating an asp.net core with Work and accounts, do we need to register our application inside azure or microsoft

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a new asp.net core MVC and i select the Work or School Account with Multiple Organization, as follow:-

[image]

now when i run my application inside visual studio i were able to login using my office 365 account, which is great. but my question is, when i deploy then web application inside a live iis , can i still login using my office 365 account? or i need to register my application inside azure or inside Microsoft first? or the login will be offered for us without any extra work?

Answer (score 0):

If you create application using `Work or School Accounts` authentication template , it will automatically register application in Azure AD of the Domain/tenant you config . Check the `appsettings.json` file of your application :

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
    "ClientId": "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a81e-729b495eb890",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

You can search the registered application by `ClientId` in Azure AD's `App registrations` blade , choose `All applications` and search by client id :

[image]

Since the app is a multi-tenant application , when a user from a different tenant signs in to the application for the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions requested by the application. If they consent, then a representation of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s tenant, and sign-in can continue. You can find the application in that tenant in `Enterprise applications` blade searching using the same client id . Please refer to below document for details about multi-tenant application .

[How to: Sign in any Azure Active Directory user using the multi-tenant application pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant)